# How to apply filters on SwiftUI Tables?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUi finally introduced tables and i  would like to print different tables from the same data by just filtering it.

For example i would like to populate the table only with adult persons

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let age: Int
    let id = UUID()
}
private var people = [
    Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez", age: 4),
    Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen", age: 18),
    Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark", age: 17),
    Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar", age: 60),
]

var body: some View {
    Table(people "where people.age>18") { //yes this is pseudocode ofc
        TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.givenName)
        TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
    }
}
```

I know i could create another array derived from the main one by just populating it with people.age>18 but i need several filterings, i have a lot of data and i would like a solution smarter than just creating several other array

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is right answer though you can try this

```
var adult:[Person]{
people.filter{person in
(person.age > 18)
}
```

}

Comment: Table(people.filter{$0.age>18}") did the trick